# mysql show columns for each of the tariff names

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
+------------+------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| dialprefix | destination            | rateinitial | tariffname  | id     |
+------------+------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
| 1          | North American Region  |     0.01710 | Call Center | 476610 |
| 1201       | United States          |     0.01710 | Call Center | 512642 |
| 1201       | United States          |     0.01110 | Direct      | 586007 |
| 1201       | United States          |     0.01055 | Standard    | 622786 |
| 1201       | United States          |     0.02949 | Premium     | 549254 |
| 1201763    | United States - OffNet |     0.01785 | Call Center | 499834 |
| 12017632   | United States - OffNet |     0.01785 | Call Center | 510969 |
| 12017636   | United States - OffNet |     0.01785 | Call Center | 510970 |
| 12017637   | United States - OffNet |     0.01785 | Call Center | 510971 |
| 12017638   | United States - OffNet |     0.01785 | Call Center | 510972 |
+------------+------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------+
```

in the tariffname column shows different names like: Call center, Direct, Premium, Standard.

what mysql query do I need to show columns for each of the tariff names and include the rate, and also remove any dialprefix duplicates and only use one to display its rate. for example:

```
+------------+------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| dialprefix | destination            | Call Center | Standard    | premium     | Direct      |
+------------+------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1201       | United States          | 0.01710     | 0.01055     | 0.02949     | 0.01110     |
+------------+------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

this query is later on json encoded and passed to data tables to display data.

this is the query that i use right now:

```
select cc_ratecard.dialprefix, cc_prefix.destination , cc_ratecard.rateinitial, cc_tariffplan.tariffname, cc_ratecard.id
from cc_ratecard, cc_prefix, cc_tariffplan
where cc_ratecard.dialprefix = cc_prefix.prefix
and cc_tariffplan.id = cc_ratecard.idtariffplan
```

Comment: I would advise adding an `sqlfiddle` example and taking a look into `pivot tables`.

Comment: MAX(CASE WHEN x = 'a' THEN y END) a, MAX(CASE WHEN x = 'b' THEN y END) b, etc... GROUP BY...